# Erro: Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou tentando converter uma string q eu puxo do banco de dados com a instrução

```
DateTime PrevisaoDataInicio = DateTime.Parse(reader["PrevisaoDataInicio"].ToString())
```

E dá o seguinte erro:

> Cadeia de caracteres não foi reconhecida como DateTime válido.

O metódo inteiro onde está sendo utilizado está abaixo:

```
private List<EntendimentoDominio> TransformaReaderEmListaDeObjeto(SqlCeDataReader reader)
    {
        var entendimentos = new List<EntendimentoDominio>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            var temObjeto = new EntendimentoDominio()
            {
                CodEntendimento = int.Parse(reader["CodEntendimento"].ToString()),
                AreaResponsavel = reader["AreaResponsavel"].ToString(),
                Modulo = reader["Modulo"].ToString(),
                Projeto = reader["Projeto"].ToString(),
                Subprojeto = reader["Subprojeto"].ToString(),
                DescricaoResumida = reader["DescricaoResumida"].ToString(),
                DescricaoDetalhada = reader["DescricaoDetalhada"].ToString(),
                CustoEstimado = reader["CustoEstimado"].ToString(),
                NomeDocumentoAnexo = reader["NomeDocumentoAnexo"].ToString(),
                CaminhoDocumentoAnexo = reader["CaminhoDocumentoAnexo"].ToString(),
                Status = reader["Status"].ToString(),
                TempoEstimado = reader["TempoEstimado"].ToString(),
                PrevisaoDataInicio = DateTime.Parse(reader["PrevisaoDataInicio"].ToString()),
                PrevisaoDataFinal = DateTime.Parse(reader["PrevisaoDataFinal"].ToString())
            };

            entendimentos.Add(temObjeto);
        }

        reader.Close();
        return entendimentos;
    }
```

Comment: O `reader["PrevisaoDataInicio"]` está a receber o que?

Comment: Qual e' o tipo da coluna `PrevisaoDataInicio` na base de dados?

Comment: meu amigo, antes de converter a string em DateTime, recomendo que você use uma variável para receber seu valor, coloque um breakpoint na linha criada, faça um teste e nos mostre o que tal variável está trazendo.

Comment: O tipo da coluna PrevisaoDataInicio é datetime também no banco de dados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O valor de PrevisaoDataInicio não pode ser convertido para um date time,

Pode ser que ele seja NULL (caso sua coluna permita isso no SQL) ou você esteja guardando ele de forma errada no banco, sugiro que faça algo assim.

```
    EntendimentoDominio obj = new EntendimentoDominio();
    string previsaoDTInici = reader["PrevisaoDataInicio"].ToString();

    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(previsaoDTInici))
      obj.PrevisaoDataInicio = DateTime.Parse(previsaoDTInici)
```

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente a propriedade PrevisaoDataInicio deve ser do tipo DateTime, certo. Segundo que a conversão que você faz está correta, porém precisa ver se vem algum valor reader["PrevisaoDataInicio"], o que eu acredito que esteja vindo, e esse campo de preferência tem que ser um campo do tipo Caractere.